# How to add a text item to a combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am new to C# from Delphi. In Delphi, TCombobox.Add takes a single, string parameter. Thus is it very simple to add a string item to a combobox.

C# confused me because Combobox.Items.Add takes a single, object parameter. There are some circumstances in which I cannot add a string var to the list of items. (I haven't identified a pattern yet; it might be if it's a property).

Googling was fruitless until...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add.aspx "This content representation is specified by the DisplayMember property. If the DisplayMember property is null, the item's ToString method is called to obtain the string that is displayed in the combo box;"

Comment: you prolly want to add the Winforms tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked several times for this question to be deleted because it is of no value to anyone. I wrote it when I was confused and bewildered and didn't know what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an WPF application, using VB.Net I got  `Component.Items.Add("String")` to work,  my guess is the string will automatically be cast to an suitable object, try to explicitly cast string in your case(not sure to what).

You can also try to assign your string to be the caption of a label and add that label to the control.

Answer (score -1):

... I found http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/416859/Csharp-Filling-ComboBox-with-an-SQL-table-column, which said

```
comboBox1.Items.Add((string) problematicVar); //problematicVar is a string
```

So I have to cast to string.

I've added this self-answered question because I wish it had existed half an hour.

Comment: Also, if someone could explain this to me, that'd be ace.

Comment: Whats the type of problematicVar?

Comment: The Add method takes any object. If you tell the combox which member of the object it should display (DisplayMember) it will do that, otherwise it will invoke ToString() on the object and display whatever string comes back.

Comment: what happened if you called problematicVar.ToString()? did it return null or String.Empty?

Comment: problematicVar was of type string